# In Vue.js, is there a way to keep component templates out of JavaScript strings?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I just worked through the Guide on Vue.js's website, and I have a bad feeling about templates for components.  It seems strange to me that they are specified in strings; sure, maybe this works for very short templates, but once you get to multiline templates, you need to start escaping your new lines and it just feels *wrong* to have html in javascript strings to begin with.  Not to mention that syntax highlighting or any other nice IDE features are useless with HTML in JS strings.

Two alternatives that are detailed in the docs are using [inline templates](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Inline-Templates), or [X-templates](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#X-Templates), but both of these options are discouraged.

The only other alternative seems to be [Single File Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html), which seems like a good option, but they are in the **Advanced** section and in the docs, it is said that for small and medium sized apps, simply using `Vue.component` should be enough.  Furthermore, Single File Components look like they're more difficult to integrate into a project, requiring tapping into the project's build system (the docs talk about Webpack and Browserify).

So I'm confused.  Do I just need to accept that my component code is going to look as messy as this example, pulled straight from the docs?

```
Vue.component('currency-input', {
  template: '\
    <span>\
      $\
      <input\
        ref="input"\
        v-bind:value="value"\
        v-on:input="updateValue($event.target.value)"\
      >\
    </span>\
  ',
......
```

Comment: Do you want to use Vue with some existing project or are you creating a new project?

Comment: I'm doing a new project. Why do you ask?

Comment: You can use X-templates, they are discouraged only because, `they separate templates from the rest of the component definition`, but if that is what you want, then it is perfectly fine.

Comment: It's not so much that that's what I want. Rather, I'm skeptical that the masses of people who use vue.js are all writing long templates in multiline JavaScript strings.  Am I missing another alternative that most people are doing?

Comment: I've only ever used the single-file components and they are definitely not so advanced to be beyond a beginners grasp. You can easily get started with Webpack or Browserify using the [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli)

Comment: It depends on architecture and the toolchain we use. In some apps, architecture requires the template be separate and independent so that it can be swapped and modifiable without touching the code or by someone who does not code, where x-templates are fine. Some others have integrated toolchains which helps in using single page components. Depends on project size, ide and other tools, people that works with the components and such mostly.

Comment: You can use a selector as `template` property's value, which targets the container element of your template. On the other hand, if you are familiar with webpack, I think it's much easier to go with vue-cli.

Comment: If you are using Webpack or Browserify, you can also simply do `template: require('template.html')` that way you can keep your template in a separate file.

Comment: "Not to mention that syntax highlighting or any other nice IDE features are useless with HTML in JS strings." Not generally true, for example IntelliJ IDEA supports HTML in strings inside JavaScript/TypeScript file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given that you are starting a new project, you can use [vue-hackernews-2.0](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0) as boilerplate, where you see lot of components already coded with webpack integration for both dev and prod env. This is also developed by core vue team and recommended in [official docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/hackernews.html).

You can see there are [different files](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0/blob/master/src/components) for each component and one component looks like following having clear separation of HTML, JS and CSS part:

```
<template>
  <li v-if="comment" class="comment">
    <div class="by">
      <router-link :to="'/user/' + comment.by">{{ comment.by }}</router-link>
      {{ comment.time | timeAgo }} ago
    </div>
    <div class="text" v-html="comment.text"></div>
    <div class="toggle" :class="{ open }" v-if="comment.kids && comment.kids.length">
      <a @click="open = !open">{{
        open
            ? '[-]'
            : '[+] ' + pluralize(comment.kids.length) + ' collapsed'
      }}</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="comment-children" v-show="open">
      <comment v-for="id in comment.kids" :id="id"></comment>
    </ul>
  </li>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'comment',
  props: ['id'],
  data () {
    return {
      open: true
    }
  },
  computed: {
    comment () {
      return this.$store.state.items[this.id]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    pluralize: n => n + (n === 1 ? ' reply' : ' replies')
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="stylus">
.comment-children
  .comment-children
    margin-left 1.5em
.comment
  border-top 1px solid #eee
  position relative
  .by, .text, .toggle
    font-size .9em
    margin 1em 0
  .by
    color #999
    a
      color #999
      text-decoration underline
  .text
    overflow-wrap break-word
    a:hover
      color #ff6600
    pre
      white-space pre-wrap
  .toggle
    background-color #fffbf2
    padding .3em .5em
    border-radius 4px
    a
      color #999
      cursor pointer
    &.open
      padding 0
      background-color transparent
      margin-bottom -0.5em
</style>
```

This uses webpack for build and adds working [config](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0/tree/master/build) as well which I myself am using in production without any issue.

Comment: Looks like the OP doesn't want to use SFC. Possibly because of Webpack or Browserify? Although I don't think it's a big problem.

Comment: @Leo That may be the case, but the [vue-hackernews-2.0](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0) provides all the config, which can help OP if setup is an issue,

Comment: Thanks so much for your response!! Looks like SFC isn't as complex as I thought.  I appreciate the advice!

Comment: @ChristopherShroba SFC is my personal favorite way of developing vue applications. But you need some knowledges of webpack (or browserify) too, because it relies on a pre-bundling process. As mentioned, vue-hackernews-2.0 and official vue-cli templates are very good learning examples.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `<template>...</template>` or `<script type="text/x-template">...</script>`, and specify the selector in `template` attribute for that.

```
<template id="myComponent">
  <div>
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
    <p><slot></slot></p>
  </div>
</template>


Vue.component('myComponent', {
  template: '#myComponent'
})
```

Simple working example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dNWrZG?editors=1010

Also, the build process of single file components is not that difficult. You can check the `webpack-simple` template: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple, the `vue-loader` will do everything for you.

Once you feel comfortable with webpack, you can take a look at the full webpack template: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack

Comment: Using this approach, is it still possible to use .vue files for each component but still ref the x-template in the html?

Answer (score 4):

From my experiences, if the template is very short, use **inline** mode is OK. If not, **x-template** also allows you to get rid of escaping line breaks. I don't see why you think these approaches are discouraged. Can you provide more information?

However, if you insist to embed long template inline, you can still do that without escaping. The answer is ES6 [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) - string wrapped within ``` `` ```:

```
template: `
  <span>
    $
    <input
      ref="input"
      v-bind:value="value"
      v-on:input="updateValue($event.target.value)"
    >
  </span>
`,
```

On the other hand, I really think vue-cli is a great tool. Webpack is something worth learning.

Comment: Thanks for your response! In the docs about X-templates and Inline templates, the last paragraph of each discourages their use.  Regarding Inline templates: "However, inline-template makes the scope of your templates harder to reason about. As a best practice, prefer defining templates inside the component using the template option or in a template element in a .vue file.", and regarding X-templates: "These can be useful for demos with large templates or in extremely small applications, but should otherwise be avoided, because they separate templates from the rest of the component definition."

Comment: @ChristopherShroba I see them as suggestions to _choose proper approach **depending on your use case**_, rather than discouraging. So what is your use case? That's what matters.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a direct answer (It's editor Specific) but i just thought i should share, but if you're using Visual Studio Code as your editor, Then you can keep your templates as part of your component and still get Syntax highlighting.

Thanks to this awesome extension
[angular-2-inline](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=natewallace.angular2-inline)

It was Originally meant for Angular 2, but it works for all ES6 Template strings (**Provided the key of Template String is "template**").

Single File components are the Recommended way, but they can become a burden when you're not building a Full-fledged SPA and you're just using Vue to enhance some HTML templates Here and there, and you don't want to get Involved with Webpack.

Don't believe it? I'm currently using it.

[image]

Comment: Excellent, it does really work as I'd like to. Too bad it will work only with the "template" key (I am defining the template in a separate file in something like  `const template = `<div>.. ` ` )  I'm using Atom but I'd even make the move for this (I'm always between VSCode and Atom anyway).

Comment: There seems to be a similar extension for Atom and the same trick works! https://github.com/colingm/language-angular-inline/tree/master/spec

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @danidee answer I was able to track an Atom extension to properly do syntax highlighting for "backticked" HTML strings. However as he indicates it will only work when the template is declared inside the very component definition (and I want to separate template in another .js file). So I did this and it's a more ellegant solution, I think:

**COMPONENT DEFINITION**

```
/* template definition */
import { csFooterView } from './csfooter-view.js?v6';

/* component definition */
const csfooter = {
  name: 'csfooter',
  props: ['projectName'],
  data: function() {
      return {
          copyrightCompany: 'CSDev'
      }
  },
  template: csFooterView.template
};

/* exports */
export { csfooter };
```

**TEMPLATE DEFINITION**

```
/**
 * VUE Footer Component
 * Template
 */

 /* template definition */
 const csFooterView = {
   template: `
    <footer class="footer bg-warning p-4 m-auto">
      <p>{{ copyrightCompany }} (c) 2020 - {{ projectName }}</p>
    </footer>
   `
 };


 export { csFooterView }
```

**ATOM SCREENSHOT WITH HTML SYNTAX HIGHLIGHTING IN THE .JS FILE**
[image: Atom Screenshot with Backticked HTML string with HTML syntax]

[Link to Atom extension](https://github.com/colingm/language-angular-inline)